# Share folders between host and Debian(guest) using Vbox

Tags: debian, virtualbox, virtual-machine

After following these steps to share folders between host and guest, it works correctly without any errors, but I have a problem: when I turn off the machine or restart it, I cannot share the same folder. I need to use `sudo mount -t vboxsf share ~/Share/` after each restart to be able to share the folder. Why did this happen?

1- Go to `Virtual Box/Device/Shared Folder (on host OS)`

2- Add a folder that you want to share in the pop-up. (on host OS) Let’s name this folder “Shared” (on host OS)

3- Now Go to Device and install guest addition.

4- Now next step would be to create a folder that you want to sync with host OS, but make sure that you are at
/home/UserName.

You can check it by typing pwd in the terminal. Now creating directory -

```
mkdir Share
```

5- Now install guest additional package (Crucial step! People generally miss this which creates an error “Unknown file type “vboxsf”)

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-ose-guest-utils
```

6- Now do the final step by mounting the folder (on guest OS)

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf share ~/Share/
```